# Codeigniter - Recuperar ID

Tags: php, codeigniter

Eu preciso recuperar o último ID inserido em uma tabela e passar este ID para o campo de outra função.

***É possível recuperar desta forma ?***

```
$negociacao = array(
        'id'             => $neg->id,
        'dt_negociacao'  => $neg->dt_negociacao,
        'atualizar'      => $neg->atualizar,
        'contrato_id'    => $neg->contrato_id,
        'id_finalizacao' => $neg->id_finalizacao,
        'crud'           => "C",
    );
$this->db->insert('tbl_devedor_negociacao', $negociacao);
$negociacao_id = $this->db->insert_id(); //Armazenar ID recuperado
$this->set_negociacao_id($negociacao_id); // Setter váriável ID armazenado

// setter ID
private function set_negociacao_id($negociacao_id = null)
{       
    return $negociacao_id;
}

// getter ID
private function get_negociacao_id()
{
    $this->set_negociacao_id();
}

// Atribuir ID recuperado Aqui
'negociacao_id'  => $this->set_negociacao_id(),
```

Comment: Seu get/set parece invertido e um pouco estranho. Esse código dá algum erro?

Comment: Não dá erro. Na função `set_negociacao_id`, se eu colocar echo ou print_r, exibe o ultimo ID inserido, mas quando return, exibe nulo.

Comment: `set` é para gravar/atribuir e `get` para retornar. O `set` tem um `return` e o `get` não faz nada...

Comment: A minha intenção é recuperar este ID de uma inserção e atribuir este ID em um campo de outra função

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Métodos get devem retornar o valor de algo e `set` gravar ou atribuir um valor em uma proriedade da classe.

```
// setter ID
private function set_negociacao_id($negociacao_id = null)
{       
    return $negociacao_id;
}


private function get_negociacao_id()
{
    $this->set_negociacao_id();
}
```

A linha abaixo devolve o valor que foi passado como argumento o que não faz muito sentido já que ele não é atribuido em lugar nenhum ou pior porque criar um método que devolve a propria entrada?

```
$this->set_negociacao_id($negociacao_id); // Setter váriável ID armazenado
```

Se entendi corretamente, para resolver o problelma primeiro o `set` deve gravar o valor passado em uma propriedada da classe o código correspondente é :

```
private $negociacao_id;
//código omitido...

public function set_negociacao_id($negociacao_id)
{       
   $this->negociacao_id = $negociacao_id;
}
```

O `get` deve retornar o valor da propriedade apenas:

```
public function get_negociacao_id()
{
    return $this->negociacao_id;
}
```

Comment: mas aí eu tenho isso `Missing argument 1 for Devedor_model::set_negociacao_id(), called in`

na função `private function set_negociacao_id($negociacao_id)`

Comment: @WagnerFilho você não pode chamar o `set` sem passar uma valor pois ele é para escrita. Se precisa apenas ler o valor use o `get`

Comment: Opa! Estava fazendo algo errado.

Comment: Deu certo!
Obrigado mesmo..